# R removing script-files before RStudio starts up

Tags: r, rstudio

when starting R I get the following error-message:

> Fatal Error: Unexpected exception: The complexity of matching the regular expression exceeded predefined bounds. Try refactoring the regular expression to make each choice made by the state machine unambiguous. This exception is thrown to prevent "eternal" matches that take an indefinite period time to locate.

The problem is caused by a script, that is loaded when starting up RStudio.
If I rename the RStudio-Desktop folder RStudio does start up without any problems.

Is there any way to stop R loading this one special file which causes the problem without having to remove/rename/hide the RStudio-Desktop folder as a whole?

For those who are interested: The buggy-script was created by copying a very long string of chars (a bit over 1.000.000 characters) from a texteditor-file to the RStudio script. RStudio terminated immediately after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: Can't you just remove everything from memory using `rm(list=ls())`, and then when you start R there won't be anything in the background?

Comment: Hi Tim, 
thanks for your input!
Unformtunately i cant do anything. 
I was a bit unclear in my starting-post about that, but after starting RStudio i just get the error-message and after that RStudio terminates. It tries to restart (and again to load the buggy script) and terminates again and so on :D

Comment: I'm not sure about the desktop version, but the server version of Rstudio creates a hidden folder called .rstudio in the home directory that contains all kinds of cached info.  In the past, I've just deleted this folder completely and it has fixed similar errors.  Note - this might not be the safest way to go...

Comment: Thanks for your answer IanK. 
I think the hidden folder .rstudio for the server version is the counterpart to the folder RStudio-Desktop for the desktop version. 
Your solution definitly works. Removing or renaming this folder stops the error, but i would like to keep all the settings from the folder RStudio-Desktop despite the one buggy file. 
I would like to not remove the whole folder but just the file, line or however it is stored, that referes to the buggy file.
Maybe someone has an idea how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Renaming (deleting) the `sources` folder in the RStudio-Desktop Directory solved the problem for me:

```
~/.rstudio-desktop/sources/
```

If you are not using Ubuntu, you can find the location of your RStudio-Desktop Directory here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State

Comment: Hello Gorka, 
thanks for your answer. 
My problem is allready a bit outdate (and i couldn't fix it the propper way, so i recreated everything by hand), but still it is good to get some input, just for the case something like this happens again to me. 

Unfortunately i cant finde a folder cold sources in my rstudie-desktop folder (maybe its because im using Windows instead of ubuntu?). 

Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi TinglTanglBob. As you can see in the link above, in Windows: 

"You can open an Explorer window into the RStudio-Desktop directory by typing the following command into Start -> Run:

For Windows Vista, 7 and 8:

%localappdata%\RStudio-Desktop
For Windows XP:

%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\RStudio-Desktop

Answer (score 0):

These commands help me to resolve similar problems also (for Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS), renaming the source folder in rstudio-desktop Directory:

```
cd ~/.rstudio-desktop/
mv sources/ ./sources-backUp
```